# How does an 8bit MCU make use of data-types over 8bits?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, data-type

how does an 8bit MCU handle 16bit output?
How does an 8bit MCU store values higher than 8bits?
I am using an attiny, on an adafruit trinket. and other 8bit MCUs.
http://www.atmel.com/devices/attiny85.aspx
I was doing some things with uint32_t datatypes, when it hit me, that it would seem like uint32_t would be an incompatible datatype. Even 2Byte data type like int seems peculiar. "[int stores a 16-bit (2-byte) value](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int)"
considering the MCU is 8bit.

I saw this link, that sounded like it would have more info, but its pages are incomplete. http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/DatatypePractices

So how does that work?
How does an 8bit MCU make use of data-types over 8bits?

Comment: Human children are often first taught to do arithmetic with single-digit arguments, and then to do operations on multi-digit place-value numbers using rules that give a sequence of single-digit operations.  Computers use very similar methods, doing multiple word-width operations to accomplish wider ones.

Comment: It's the compiler that convert the 32-bit operations into 8-bit instructions.

Comment: Is `MCU` micro controller unit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is that the processor does math in 8-bit chunks, so it takes more instructions than it would on a 32-bit processor.

A good answer is found in [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166218/how-can-a-8-bit-cpu-calculate-big-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Actually a 1-bit MCU could be used to execute code (e.g. C/C++) with N-bit numbers. Not very fast as it will require *O(N)* operations for addition and subtraction.

To better understand this for the 8-bit AVR MCU used in Arduino I recommend reading the [Instruction Set Description Manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf), [AVR/GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc) and assembler code listings for some sketches. This will reveal the secret(s) behind this "alien technology/magic".

Cheers!